# Aligning text and icons in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

[image: click to view image]

I want it so all the icons are where they are and the text to the right needs more space between the icon and the text so all text starts at the same place.

Like this:

```
ICON  TEXT
ICON  TEXT
ICON  TEXT
ICON  TEXT
ICON  TEXT
ICON  TEXT
```

And not:

```
ICON TEXT
ICON   TEXT
ICON  TEXT
ICON TEXT
ICON  TEXT


<ul>
<li><i class"fa fa-icon"></i> <a href="example.com">Example</a></li>
<li><i class"fa fa-icon"></i> <a href="example.com">Example</a></li>
<li><i class"fa fa-icon"></i> <a href="example.com">Example</a></li>
<li><i class"fa fa-icon"></i> <a href="example.com">Example</a></li>
<li><i class"fa fa-icon"></i> <a href="example.com">Example</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either make all the icons the same width or use the CSS grid.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul.width i {
  width: 1.5em;
}

ul.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 0 0.5em;
}
ul.grid > li {
  display: contents;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<ul class="width">
  <li><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> <a href="example.com">envelope</a></li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> <a href="example.com">graduation-cap</a></li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-school"></i> <a href="example.com">school</a></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> <a href="example.com">instagram</a></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i> <a href="example.com">fa-linkedin-in</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<ul class="grid">
  <li><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> <a href="example.com">envelope</a></li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> <a href="example.com">graduation-cap</a></li>
  <li><i class="fas fa-school"></i> <a href="example.com">school</a></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i> <a href="example.com">instagram</a></li>
  <li><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i> <a href="example.com">fa-linkedin-in</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put those text in a tag like  and add a few pixel left padding. that'll work. If you could git some sample code. Explanation would have been easier.

```css
.text{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
    
    <div class="elements">
      <span></span> 
      <span class="text">Home</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: No that is not working. its just the original but then a bit to the side

Comment: That's because those icons are not in same size. If those are same size then there will be same distance between text and icon